# Google or Bing maps API - creating and using your own map

Tags: google-maps, bing-maps

What I need is the following.

Whenever I add any instance of object in my website, I need the server to add the location of the object to my own map either in Google maps or Bing maps (Bing maps docs are more clear therefore I'm going to use Bing).

Later, whenever I view the object in my site, the map should point to the location of the object and other my map objects in the same map.

How can this be achieved? Do I need to hold all the coordinates and object descriptions in my server, or somehow it is saved in the google or bing.

I went through the docs, but couldn't find any information I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store them on your server and load them into the map on your webpage. There are ways with both google (fusion tables) and bing (spatial data services) of storing them with the provider but if you are already storing a copy for your website you are better off keeping them there for the map rather than maintaining two copies.

I'm not sure how technical you are but this best architecture approach is this:

1) Write a database query that finds objects to show on your map, ideally filtered by whatever the user can use to filter objects elsewhere on your site. Add to this query a filter by geographical bounding box (the range of latitude and longitude that can be seen on your map at any one point). The bounding box filter is just a simple sql BETWEEN clause but will mean you dont have to load every single object on to the map.

2) write a "webservice" that uses the database query in 1) and turns the results into JSON. This approach will lead to a much cleaner seperation between your mapping code in javascript and your server side code in the webservice.

3) Write your mapping frontend in Bing using javascript and use something like Jquery to read data from the webservice as the map is moved around re-load data that know should be shown on the new map view. As the data will be in JSON its much easier as JSON will just give you javascript versions of your objects